# relocation truncated, R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol

Tags: c, declaration, relocation

In this C program, I needed to make a a queue applciation in a structured approach. As I was trying to run this program in netbeans, i saw that i was getting a relocation truncated error. My professor told me to run it in Clion and I'm still getting the same exact error.  The error is specifically stating that im having undefined reference to 'dequeue', 'enqueue', and 'getCurrentSize'.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool enqueue(int** queue, int* size, int value);
void dequeue(int** queue, int* size);
int getCurrentSize(int size);
void display(int* intQueue, int size);

int main()
{
    int input;
    int initSize = 3;
    int size = 0;
    char option = 'a';
    char answer = 'y';
    int value;

    bool enqueueResult, dequeueResult = true;

    int* queue = (int*)malloc(initSize * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i<initSize; i++)
        queue[i] = 0;

    printf("This program implements Queues using structured programming. Enter "
        "a number from 1 to 4 . \n"
        "1. To enqueue a number \n"
        "2. To dequeue a number \n"
        "3. To get the current size of the queue \n"
        "4. To see the contents within the queue \n"
        "5. Exit the program");
    scanf("%d", &input);

    switch (input)
    {
    case 1:
        enqueueResult = enqueue(&queue, &size, value);

        if (enqueueResult == true)
            printf("The number has been put into the queue!");

        else
            printf("The number was not able to be enqueued!");
        break;

    case 2:
        dequeue(&queue, &size);

        printf("Number was dequeued from the queue");
        break;

    case 3:
        printf("The current size of the queue is: " + getCurrentSize(size));
        break;
    }
    free(queue);
    return 0;
}


//********************************************************
//QueueLibrary.c below

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool enqueue(int** queue, int* size, int value)
{
    int maxSize = *size + 1;

    if (*queue == NULL)
        return false;

    if (*size < 0)
        return false;

    if (*size == maxSize)
    {
        int* copy = (int*)malloc((maxSize + 1) * sizeof(int));

        if (copy == NULL)
            return false;
        maxSize += 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < *size; i++)
            copy[i] = (*queue)[i];

        free(*queue);
        *queue = copy;
    }

    for (int i = *size; i > *size - 1; i--)
    {
        (*queue)[i] = value;
        printf("The value %d has been added to the queue\n", (*queue)[i]);
    }
    *size += 1;
    return true;
}

void dequeue(int** intQueue, int* size)
{
    printf("%d has left the queue\n", *intQueue[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < *size; i++)
        (*intQueue)[i] = (*intQueue)[i + 1];

    if (*size != 0)
        *size -= 1;

    else
        printf("There is nothing left in the queue\n");

}

int getCurrentSize(int size)
{
    return size;
}

void display(int* intQueue, int size)
{
    printf("The integers in the queue are :\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d\n", intQueue[i]);

}
```

[This is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNO58.png)

Comment: You should show the exact error messages you're getting and the command line that produced them.

Comment: i edited the the post to show the error

Comment: You are failing to compile and link in the `QueueLibrary.c`.  You need to update your build process to be sure that file is handled too.